# adding str(variable) with subscript to matplotlib label

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to add a label with such as this to my plot:

plt.plot(self.x, y,label = '$L_{}$'.format(str(component)))

But, for component = 10, 11, 12, the result is as shown in the figure..only the first character of  component is printed in subscript...

[image]

please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use double `{{}}` curly brackets and also, you don't need to convert to string. For more explanation, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53782465/4932316) answer.

```
plt.plot(self.x, y, label = '$L_{{{}}}$'.format(component))
```